# how to add my own function in a post/delete/put- request in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, post

It is possible to add my own funtion in a post/put/delete request in angular? like:

```
  openAlert() {
    this.dialog.open(AlertComponent, {
      width: '30%',
      position: {top: '0%', right: '15%'}
    })
  }
  addStudent(borrow: Borrow): Observable<Borrow> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.student_Url}`, stdent, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((newStudent: Student) => this.log(`added student w/ ${newStundent}`)),
      map(() => { return student; }),
      catchError(err => {
        alert(err.error.message);
        console.error(err.message);
        console.log("Error deteced");
        return of(err.message);
      })
    )
  }
```

so i would add the funtion openAlert after the post. i can put it before the first return but it is useless because i want to show the dialog when the addStudent funtion dont get any error (catchError), but if i put it at the beginning, i will see the dialog field too in the case i get an error. so i get the dialog field in the case the post failed too but i want to prevent it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways of doing so:

1. use `tap()`:

   `tap((newStudent: Student) => this.openAlert()),`
2. in a `subscribe()` block:

   `return this.httpClient.post(${this.student_Url}, stdent, this.httpOptions).subscribe(data => this.openAlert())`
3. using the **observable**:

   `this.addStudent.subscribe(data => this.openAlert())`

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i have the same problem. so when i get something in cachError, the dialog still appear. do you know if it is possible to break/stop the function if i get error in cacherror? i thing it will solve when i add the tap after cachterror

Comment: 2. and 3. should only call `this.openAlert()` when there was no error.

Comment: ah okay thank you. It Works (with 1) i add  the var i in the funcion addStudtent(student: Student, i=1), when i get a error? i=i+1 and befor a display the dialog i said if(i==2) return. So i just have a dialog if i==1 ;-)